# what's the difference between `fseek`, `lseek`, `seekg`, `seekp`?

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I was asked by an interviewer that how would I implement `tail` (yes, the one in linux shell). My answer was, first seek to the end of the file, then read characters one-by-one forward, if encounters a `\n`, means one line is down, blah blah blah. I assume my answer is correct.

Then I found this problem, which seek should I use to implement `tail`? I thought I can simply use `seekg` (C++ thing?), but I was told that I should use `lseek` (linux system call?).

So including `fseek` (ANSI C thing?), which one should I use to implement `tail`?
And is there any big difference between them?

Comment: Pretty sure `fseek` is just a wrapper for `lseek` on Linux.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin, I expect that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `seekg` when using the C++ IOstreams library. `seekp` is no use here, since it sets the put pointer.

Use `fseek` when using the C stdio library. Use `lseek` when using low-level POSIX file descriptor I/O.

The difference between the various seek functions is just the kind of file/stream objects on which they operate. On Linux, `seekg` and `fseek` are probably implemented in terms of `lseek`.

Comment: So, I can successfully implement 'tail` using `fseek` in `C` or `seekg` in `C++`, right?

Comment: @Alcott: Yes. `seekg`/IOstreams is the C++ "native" I/O library, but stdio might be faster. Your choice.

Comment: I'm using linux, so am I supposed to pick `lseek` over `fseek`?

Comment: No, you're supposed to pick `fseek` because it works with stdio, which is easy to use, portable and buffered. `lseek` is for low-level I/O.

Comment: For many of the standard utilities, stdio is not acceptable because its buffering could consume extra bytes of non-seekable input that the utility is specified to leave unconsumed for the next utility invoked (in a shell script) to have access to. Thus `lseek`/`read`/etc. are generally preferred to `fseek`/`fread`/etc. However, in the specific case of tail I suspect it doesn't matter.

Comment: @R.., `lseek` is not buffered? Then does it mean, I should do the buffer by myself in the code?

Comment: @Alcott: if you want to use `lseek` and you want buffering, then yes, you're on your own.

Comment: @R..: but for line-oriented programs, isn't stdio with line buffering sufficient in most cases?

Comment: No, it's not. There's really no such thing as line-buffered input because you can't tell where the line ends until you've already read it (and thus you can't perform large reads). Terminal devices have their own line buffering in canonical mode, but that's separate.

Comment: The posix API also has the advantage of polymorphism for file descriptors. The int can be a handle to a file, a socket or another file-like resource in the Unix tradition.