# Invalid conversion from 'FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}' to 'int'

Tags: c++, linux, file, lseek

When trying to compile this little example...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *foo;
    foo = fopen("bar.txt", "rt");
    lseek(foo, 5, SEEK_CUR);           // This line is getting compiler error
    fclose(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

...I get a compiler error regarding the call to `lseek()`. The output is:

```
main.cpp|8|error:     invalid conversion from ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]|
unistd.h|334|error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘__off_t lseek(int, __off_t, int)’ [-fpermissive]|
```

For the record: I have also tried using both `lseek(*foo, 5, SEEK_CUR);` and `lseek(&foo, 5, SEEK_CUR);`, but that only makes things worse. (I really didn't expect that to solve anything either.)

Referring to the [man-page for lseek(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lseek):

> **Synopsis**
> off_t lseek(int *fildes*, off_t *offset*, int *whence*);
>
> **Description**
> The lseek() function shall set the file offset for the open file description associated with the file descriptor *fildes*, as follows:
>
> [........]

I interpret this to mean that the first argument should be the *file descriptor*, which in this case is *foo*.

**Q: What's wrong here?**

Comment: Never mix the stdio library with raw file handling. Buffers are involved and stuff gets messy. Use one or the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to seek within file, use [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/). I never saw lseek used this way

More info: [what's the difference between `fseek`, `lseek`, `seekg`, `seekp`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349470/whats-the-difference-between-fseek-lseek-seekg-seekp)

Comment: Thank you! That was just what I was looking for. :D The answer to the question [Read/write from file descriptor at offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780919/read-write-from-file-descriptor-at-offset) got me confused.